# How to write and then read only one line from serial /dev/ttyACM0

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, arduino, cat

I'm trying to write to my arduino through the serial port:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<> /dev/ttyACM0 
echo "v" >&3
cat <&3  
exec 3>&-
```

The based on the letter it receives it should return the value from one of the sensors. For simplicity I replaced that with millis().

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    if (incomingByte == 118){
      Serial.println(millis());
      Serial.end();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I execute that bash script, it never returns the promt, the "cat" command keeps waiting for more.

I have tried Serial.write(0) and Serial.write(4) (instead of Serial.end()) that are supposed to be EOF chars, but it still won't return the promt.

I also tried 
    cat <&3 | head -n 1

But still, cat never returns.

Any thoughts?

(I'm doing all of this on a mr3020 with no pendrive for extra space, so python is out of the question)

Comment: Did you try without cat command? Just  **head -n 1 <&3**

Comment: Do the above commands work via a 'tty session'?  Did you include the code for serial I/O?  I did something similar using 'screen' - might be helpful: http://web-tech.ga-usa.com/2011/06/arduino-serial-time-with-screen-and-other-tools/  :)

Comment: Just **head -n 1 <&3** worked fine. Thanks!! :)